# Showing an identity between polynomials whose coefficients involve combinatorial identities

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to show that
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \sum_{l=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-2k}{2}\rfloor} (-1)^l \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-2k-l}{l} \frac{n-2k}{n-2k-l} x^{n-2k-2l} = x^n.
$$
If we "compare coefficients", then we get $x^n$ on the left if $k = l = 0$, hence 
$$
 \binom{n}{0} \binom{n}{0} \frac{n}{n} x^{n} = x^n
$$
is valid. But the other sums look quite messy...

Comment: Is there a typo somewhere?  Is the exponent on $x$ correct?  It looks to me like on the left you only get $x^n$ when $k=l=0.$  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @saulspatz I corrected $(-1)^l$, it was $(-1)^k$ before, but otherwise its correct. Essentially if we set $u_n := \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (-1)^k \frac{n-k}{k} \binom{n-k}{k} x^{n-2k}$ then our sum becomes $$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{k} u_{n-2k}.$$ Maybe this looks better.

Comment: I'm sorry by I still don't understand.  You say "on the left it adds to $x^n$ iff $k=l.$"  Now when $k=l,$ the exponent is $n-2k-2l=n-4k,$ so I don't follow you.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh, sorry yes you are totally right! This was a stupid start from me, I deleted it!

Answer (score 2):

Putting $n=2N$ we want to show for integral $N\geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{l=0}^{N-k}(-1)^l\binom{2N}{k}\binom{2N-2k-l}{l}
\frac{2N-2k}{2N-2k-l}x^{2N-2k-2l}=x^{2N}
\end{align*}

> At first we derive a somewhat more convenient representation.
>   We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^N}&\color{blue}{\sum_{l=0}^{N-k}(-1)^l\binom{2N}{k}\binom{2N-2k-l}{l}
> \frac{2N-2k}{2N-2k-l}x^{2N-2k-2l}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{l=0}^{N-k}(-1)^{N-k-l}\binom{2N}{k}\binom{N-k+l}{N-k-l}
> \frac{2N-2k}{N-k+l}x^{2l}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{l=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-l}\binom{2N}{N-k}\binom{k+l}{k-l}
> \frac{2k}{k+l}x^{2l}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^N\sum_{k=l}^{N}(-1)^{k-l}\binom{2N}{N-k}\binom{k+l}{k-l}
> \frac{2k}{k+l}x^{2l}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{l=0}^N\sum_{k=0}^{N-l}(-1)^{k}\binom{2N}{N-k-l}\binom{k+2l}{k}
> \frac{2k+2l}{k+2l}x^{2l}}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we exchange the summation order of the inner sum $l\to N-k-l$.
- In (2) we exchange the summation order of the outer sum $k\to N-k$.
- In (3) we exchange the series.
- In (4) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $k=0$.

> Let's call the polynomial $P(x)$. We can easily derive from (4) the  coefficient $[x^{2N}]$ of the highest power and see
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{2N}]P(x)=1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Next we consider for integral $N>0$ and $0\leq t<N$ according to (4):
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{[x^{2t}]P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-t}(-1)^{k}\binom{2N}{N-k-t}\binom{k+2t}{k}
> \frac{2k+2t}{k+2t}}\\
> &\quad=\sum_{k=0}^{N-t}(-1)^{k}\binom{2N}{N-k-t}\binom{k+2t}{k}
> \left(1+\frac{k}{k+2t}\right)\\
> &\quad=\sum_{k=0}^{N-t}(-1)^{k}\binom{2N}{N-k-t}\binom{k+2t}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{N-t}(-1)^{k}\binom{2N}{N-k-t}\binom{k+2t-1}{k-1}\tag{5}\\
> &\quad=\sum_{k=0}^{N-t}(-1)^{k}\binom{2N}{N-k-t}\binom{k+2t}{k}
> +\sum_{k=0}^{N-t-1}(-1)^{k}\binom{2N}{N-k-t-1}\binom{k+2t}{k}\tag{6}\\
> &\quad=\sum_{k=0}^{N-t}\binom{2N}{N-k-t}\binom{-2t-1}{k}
> +\sum_{k=0}^{N-t-1}\binom{2N}{N-k-t-1}\binom{-2t-1}{k}\tag{7}\\
> &\quad=\binom{2N-2t-1}{N-t}-\binom{2N-2t-1}{N-t-1}\tag{8}\\
> &\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (5) we multiply out and apply to the right-hand series the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (6) we shift the index of the right-hand series to start with $k=0$.
- In (7) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ twice.
- In (8) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)* twice.

Comment: Verified. Good work. (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for verification and the credit.